# Selenium webdriver error - stale element refernce

Tags: python, selenium

So i tried to practice on my selenium skills using the website https://instagram.com

I Can Find an object using selenium & click, can not send keys to it.

So basically , i tried to automate comments on Instagram , iv'e found the "Add Comment" , successfully clicked on it , but when i tried to send keys i got an error.

#### CODE SECTION:

```
comment_picture = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')
    for l in comment_picture:
        try:
            print l.get_attribute("class")
            l.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            l.send_keys('test')
```

#### ERROR SECTION:

Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
[image]

The expected result should be that i can comment on each photo on Instagram.
I don't want an answer. i really want to learn selenium. if someone know that i'm doing wrong , it would be great if i will get an hint and not a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

`stale element` is because the element has been modified when you click, you have to re-find the element like this

```
comment_picture = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea')
index = 1 # xpath index start from 1
for txt in comment_picture:
    try:
        txt.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        # re-search the textarea
        txt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//textarea)[%s]' % index) 
        txt.send_keys('test')
        index = index + 1
```

Comment: Thanks learnin , but i do not fully understand your code. please explain . 
After some changes , iv'e got an error that said "cant focus on element." do you know this error?

thanks !!!!!

Comment: in addition, im sure everyone would like to know how you get this answer .

Comment: @learnin , i see that is work works. can you please explain the code and how you get the solution ? thanks. after that we can close this case

Comment: it already explained, where in the code you didn't understand?

Comment: how you got it? I'm not interested in a solution, I'm interested in learning selenium and learn how to troubleshoot by my self.

Comment: there are no more to explain or any hidden step, if you get `stale element reference` then you have to search again the element.

Answer (score 0):

element references returned by the `.find_element_*` functions are from the intial page load.  When you `click()`, you are navigating away from the intial page, making all of the element references stale.  You will need to call find_elements again before you send keys to the new elements.

Comment: Thanks Corey , but i don't fully understand.
this performed in a for loop for all elements on the website , and i can access to the input area , but i can not send keys.

Comment: someone help ? please. i'm stuck on that.

Comment: Corey ? anything?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are signed in and able to comment.
also `executable_path='your/path'`

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/Bs0y4Myg3Hk/')
comment=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')
comment.send_keys('hello')
comment.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186983/discussion-on-answer-by-amjasd-masdhash-selenium-webdriver-error-stale-element).

Comment: Works only for specified picture. the main issue that is not working on the main page on FOR loop while search each "add comment" element.